# Exercise 3.D. in Robert G. Bartle's book

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let us consider the problem 3.D. in the book

$\textbf{The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure}$

of Robert G. Bartle

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be the $\sigma-$algebra of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. If $(a_n)$  is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers and if we define $\mu$ by
$$
\mu(\emptyset)=0; \quad \mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E}a_n, \quad E\ne\emptyset,
$$
then $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Conversely, every measure on $\mathcal{A}$ is obtained in this way for some sequence $(a_n)$ in $\overline{R}^+$.

I am stuck in proving the countably additive property of $\mu$.

**My attempt.** I intend to use the theory of double index series to prove countably additive property.

Thank you for all solutions.

Comment: can you see finite additivity?

Comment: Nope, I cannot see the finite additivity.

Comment: Maybe it's too obvious. If we have $A, B \subseteq \mathbb N$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $\mu(A \cup B) = \sum_{n \in A \cup B} a_n = \sum_{n \in A} a_n + \sum _{n \in B} a_n = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$, since A and B are disjoint. That's finite additivity. Countable additivity is completely analogous.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But I do not think it is too obvious for the case finite additivity and countable additivity. We have to use some results related to theory of real series to prove two properties.

Comment: That's true. But luckily, we have $a_n \geq 0$, so any $\sum a_j$ can only diverge to $+\infty$. That's the lesson to learn here.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of countable additivity:
\begin{align*}
\mu\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)&=\sum_{n\in\bigcup _{i=1}^\infty E_i}a_n
\end{align*}
Notice that $(E_i)$ is a disjoint sequence, then n belongs to **one and only one** $E_i$, which means:
$$\sum_{n\in\bigcup _{i=1}^\infty E_i}a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n\in E_i}a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_i)$$

The proof of every measure on A is obtained in this way for some sequence $(a_n)$ in $\overline{R}^+$:

For every $E\subset N$, $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}{\{n_i\}}$, where $n_i\in N$ or $\{n_i\}=\emptyset$. From the countable additivity of $\mu$ we know that:
$$\mu(E) = \sum_{n \in E}\mu(\{n\})$$
We set $\mu(\{n\}):=a_n$, which establishs the proposition.

Answer (score 0):

We have to check the following

- $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, by definition
- $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E}a_n\geq 0$, since $a_n\geq 0$, for all $n$.
- Let $\{E_k\}$ be disjoint, then\begin{align*}
  \mu\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right)&=\sum_{n\in\bigcup E_k}a_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n\in E_k}a_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu (E_k).
  \end{align*}

Thus, $\mu$ is a measure on ***X***. Conversely, for $(a_n)$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^+$, we can obtain any measure on ***X*** using the enunciated definition of $\mu$.